# Registering a signal handler with wpa_supplicant p2p DBus interface

Tags: c, gdbus, wpa-supplicant

I'm running into issues trying to register to receive the "InvitationReceived" signal from wpa_supplicant's dbus interface for p2p using the `gdbus` library in C.

I can create a proxy connection to the P2P dbus interface just fine and call methods on it, but when I try to connect a signal handler to the proxy, I just get the following error saying the signal is invalid (the relevant output from the code sample):

> (process:6764): GLib-GObject-WARNING **:
>   /tmp/buildd/glib2.0-2.42.1/./gobject/gsignal.c:2461: signal
>   'InvitationReceived' is invalid for instance '0x909ae0' of type
>   'GDBusProxy'

Which is weird, since "InvitationReceived" is the name of the signal as defined by the [wpa_supplicant dbus api](https://w1.fi/wpa_supplicant/devel/dbus.html).

Code Sample:

```
static void on_wpa_ready (GObject *source_object,
                          GAsyncResult *res,
                          gpointer user_data) {
    g_print("on_wpa_ready\n");

    GError *error = NULL;
    GVariant *output;  

    GDBusProxy *p2p_proxy = g_dbus_proxy_new_for_bus_finish(res, &error);
    if (error) {
        g_print("proxy finish error: %s\n", error->message);
        g_error_free(error);
        return;
    }

    /* call p2p_listen */   
    g_clear_error(&error);
    output = NULL;
    output = g_dbus_proxy_call_sync(p2p_proxy,
                      "Listen",
                      g_variant_new("(i)", 0), //params
                      G_DBUS_CALL_FLAGS_NONE,
                      10, //timeout_msec
                      NULL,
                      &error
    );

    if (error) {
        g_print("Listen call error: %s\n", error->message);
        g_error_free(error);
        g_print("continuing...\n");
    }
    else {
        /* it gets to this print stmt, so the method was able to be called */
        g_print("Listen successful\n");
    }

    /* register for signal from p2p device */
    /* THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR IS */
    error = NULL;
    g_signal_connect(p2p_proxy,
                     "InvitationReceived",
                     G_CALLBACK(on_signal), // stub func that does something simple
                     NULL);

}

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    GMainLoop *loop;

    /* connect to wpa_supplicant p2p dbus interface */
    g_dbus_proxy_new_for_bus(G_BUS_TYPE_SYSTEM,
                     G_DBUS_PROXY_FLAGS_NONE,
                     NULL,
                     "fi.w1.wpa_supplicant1", //name,
                     "/fi/w1/wpa_supplicant1/Interfaces/0", //object_path,
                     "fi.w1.wpa_supplicant1.Interface.P2PDevice", //interface_name,
                     NULL,
                     on_wpa_ready, //callback,
                     NULL);
    );

    loop = g_main_loop_new(NULL, FALSE);
    g_main_loop_run(loop);
}
```

Is there some special path that needs to be appended to the signal name? Or am I supposed to use a different proxy for registering signal handlers from the one used to call methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Finally found the problem / a solution -- posting here for future gdbus users)

From the [GIO documentation for GDBusProxy](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GDBusProxy.html):

> The generic “g-properties-changed” and “g-signal” signals are not very
>   convenient to work with. Therefore, the recommended way of working
>   with proxies is to subclass GDBusProxy, and have more natural
>   properties and signals in your derived class.

As this paragraph hints, it turns out that the base `GDBusProxy` class only supports the two generic signals that all interfaces are guaranteed to have: `g-properties-changed` and `g-signal`. Registering for the `g-signal` signal on a proxy invokes the callback whenever *any* signal is emitted by the object of the given proxy, including the one I happened to be looking for in this case.

Instead of going the subclassing route suggested in the documentation, I ended up just using a quick-and-dirty catchall handler:

```
// the new snippet for connecting a signal handler:
g_signal_connect(p2p_proxy,
                 "g-signal",
                 G_CALLBACK(on_signal), // stub func that does something simple
                 NULL);
```

And then checking for which signal was actually called in the callback function:

```
/* callback function */
static void on_signal (GDBusProxy *proxy,
                       gchar *sender_name,
                       gchar *signal_name,
                       GVariant *params,
                       gpointer user_data) {
    if (g_strcmp0(signal_name, "InvitationReceived")) {
        // ignore all irrelevant signals
        return;
    } 

    g_print("InvitationReceived signal received\n");

    /* other handling code.... */
}
```